# Power BI: Finding average of averages and STDEV.P of averages

Tags: average, powerbi, dax, calculated-columns, standard-deviation

All,

My overall objective is to find outliers within an aggregated data set vs the underlying detail for different date ranges. The issue I am having is that  Power BI is averaging the SalesPerDay and finding the STDEV.P at the daily level which is the grain of the raw data. I need to first find the average Sales, then find the average of those averages for that "rolled up" data set. Same with STDEV.P. Need to find the STDEV of the "rolled up" averages. Screenshot below depicting how I need the tool to aggregate.

I have brought the Sales column into my dashboard, dimentionalized by user, and set to AVERAGE to get average SalesPerDay.

Then I created the new measure

```
newavg = CALCULATE(AVERAGE(SalesPerDay[Sales]),ALLSELECTED())
```

Which is finding the overall average, but at the daily level vs the aggregated level.

I also tried

```
newSTDV = CALCULATE(STDEV.P(AVERAGE(SalesPerDay[Sales])),ALLSELECTED())
```

But you cannot find the STDEV.P of a calculation.

Thank you.

[image: Data Image]

Comment: I'm not sure I completely follow. What does your desired output look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the iterator functions, which take a table or column of data as a grouping, and then applies a calculation on that group.

Example of one would be SUMX.  In the example below, it would do a grouping based on Product.  Within each product it would get the total of qty and multiply it by the sum of x.  It would then sum the results of that calculation into a total.

```
SUMX( VALUES( table1 [ Product ] ), [Qty] * [x] )
```

There also being averagex, minx, maxx, plus for the statistical functions there is STDEVX.P and STDEVX.S